# How can I fix this error? I am trying to deploy stub API on AWS. I have fired sls deploy command

Tags: typescript, serverless-framework

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'G:\scalex\Agency portal.build\node_modules'
at Object.unlinkSync (fs.js:1162:3)
at TypeScriptPlugin. (G:\scalex\Agency portal\node_modules\serverless-plugin-typescript\dist\src\index.js:172:24)
at Generator.next ()
at G:\scalex\Agency portal\node_modules\serverless-plugin-typescript\dist\src\index.js:7:71
at new Promise ()
at __awaiter (G:\scalex\Agency portal\node_modules\serverless-plugin-typescript\dist\src\index.js:3:12)
at TypeScriptPlugin.copyDependencies (G:\scalex\Agency portal\node_modules\serverless-plugin-typescript\dist\src\index.js:166:16)
at TypeScriptPlugin. (G:\scalex\Agency portal\node_modules\serverless-plugin-typescript\dist\src\index.js:44:28)
at Generator.next ()
at fulfilled (G:\scalex\Agency portal\node_modules\serverless-plugin-typescript\dist\src\index.js:4:58)

```
 For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and be sure to add additional context details to your question. Currently it's all code, it would be helpful to know more about what you're trying to do and what you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a known permissions issue with the TypeScriptPlugin. You may try following the advice of others here, and removing the `.build` and `.serverless` directories and re-running the command:

https://github.com/prisma-labs/serverless-plugin-typescript/issues/170